# Debian Wheezy and PHP 7.1 installation

Tags: php-7.1, debian-7.6.0

I have ISPConfig 3.1 on Debian wheezy with php 5.4 and php 5.3.
I am trying to install php 7.1 on the same server according to this manual for Debian Jessie:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/
and of course it does not work. In the step "make" it says:
"No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

I also found this instruction:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-php-7-on-debian-linux-8-jessie-wheezy-using-apt-get/, however I cannot use it because I need php5.4 and PHP 5.3 on my server as well.

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

If someone else (like me) still needs to install php 7.1 or newer on Debian 7.X (wheezy), please be informed that I followed [this instruction](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-php-7-on-debian-linux-8-jessie-wheezy-using-apt-get/) (just scroll down to `Configuration for Debian 7.x “Wheezy”` section) and it worked for me like a charm!